# Add timestamp in SP - issue resolution

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer

I'm currently working on operational workflow/issue management and I need details such as

1. How long does the team acknowledge the issue from the time a query was received from client
2. How long for the team to resolve the issue

I have 4 status

- Open (default)
- In progress (acknowledge)
- Pending (if theyy need addtl info from client)
- Resolved

I need a timestamp when status = *In progress* and another timestamp if status = *Resolved*. I tried using the workflow and if but whenever the status changes from in progress to resolved, the timestamp under the "*timestamp in progress*" column gets deleted.

How can I save both timestamps? *Note that 1 query = 1 current item*

Comment: You are using SharePoint wofklow or MS Flow? for instance: You can add *write to log* and add curent time to history. Or you just need to have Column text with more lines and add new line in new state.

Comment: Hi, I'm using sharepoint

Comment: So you can log it into workflow history, or you can create another 2 system columns (dateTime) and use them for InProgress and Resolved times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Designer workflow to only set the "timestamp in progress" column if it's currently blank. That way, if it already has a value, the value won't be deleted.

I'd probably use date/time fields for the timestamp columns. Make sure you don't specify a default value. You could also use text columns if you want.

Workflow pseudocode:

```
If TimestampInProgress is empty
    Set TimestampInProgress = CurrentItem:Modified
```

Comment: Hi, should I use a workflow for this? Or I can use a calculated column field? Thanks!

Comment: The problem that I see in this solution is the timestamp might change whenever the user amends the current item. It might update the timestampinprogress based on "modified". Or will it not?

Comment: @HareeSac If you set the value using a workflow with the logic above, it will only set the value once. I updated my response to clarify. Give it a try and let us know if you need any further info.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your solution worked!!!